# showing softkeyboard in android on landscape orientation

Tags: android, keyboard, show-hide

```
EditText textView = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
textView.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I use this code to open soft keyboard automatically .
it works fine in normal situation but when I change it to landscape orientation `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` 
in manifest, it stops working.
what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show it forcefully.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```